# While loop and boolean function

Tags: c++

Hello guys I'm not an expert on the subject so please excuse my pour skills. I finished my program and it works fine (calculator). The problem is that now I don't know where to locate the while loop in conjunct with the Boolean function to repeat the process once it is done with a task (once the program completes a math operation). Any help, comment or suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.!!

```
 #include <iostream>  
 #include <math.h> 
 #include <cmath>


 int main()
 {

 double a=0.0;
 double b=0.0;
 double c=0.0;
 bool repeat = true;


do {
using namespace std;
int x;

cout << "**********************************" << endl;
cout << "|                                |" << endl;
cout << "| 0 - Quit                       |" << endl;
cout << "| 1 - Add                        |" << endl;
cout << "| 2 - Subtract                   |" << endl;
cout << "| 3 - Divide                     |" << endl;
cout << "| 4 - Multiply                   |" << endl;
cout << "| 5 - Raise X to the power Y     |" << endl;
cout << "| 6 - Sine ( x )                 |" << endl;
cout << "| 7 - Cosine ( x )               |" << endl;
cout << "| 8 - Tangent ( x )              |" << endl;
cout << "**********************************" << endl;
cout << "Enter a selection, please: " << endl; 
cin >> x;




switch (x)
{


{
case 1:
cout << " Enter the first value" <<endl;
cin >> a ;
cout << " Enter second value " << endl;
cin >> b; 
c=a+b;
cout << "The addition of " << a << " and "<< b << "is" << c << endl;

break;
bool repeat = true;
 }



 {
case 2:
cout << " Enter the first value" << endl;
cin >> a ;
cout << " Enter the second value " << endl;
cin >> b; 
c=a-b;
cout << "The subtraction of " << a << " and " << b << " is: " << c << endl;

break;
bool repeat = true;
}


{
case 3:
cout << " Enter the first value" <<endl;
cin >> a ;
cout << " Enter the second value " << endl;
cin >> b; 
c=a/b;
cout << " The division os " << a << " and " << b << "is" << c << endl;

break;
bool repeat = true;
 }


 {
case 4:
cout << " Enter the first value" <<endl;
cin >> a ;
cout << " Enter the second value " << endl;
cin >> b; 
c=a*b;
 cout << " The product of " << a << " times " << b << " is " << c << endl;
 break;
 bool repeat = true;
 }

  {
  case 5:
 cout << " Enter the value to be exponentiated " <<endl;
 cin >> a ;
 cout << " Enter the exponent" << endl;
 cin >> b; 
 c= pow(a,b);
 cout << a << " Rased to the power of " << b << " is: " << c << endl;

 break;
 bool repeat = true;
  }


  { 
  case 6:
  cout << " Enter the value that you want the sine to be taken of" <<endl;
  cin >> a ;
  c=sin(a);
  cout << " The sine of " << a << " is: " << c << endl ;

  break;
  bool repeat = true;
   }

   {
  case 7:
  cout << " Enter the value that you want the cosine to be taken of" <<endl;
  cin >> a ;
  c=cos(a);
  cout << " The cosine of " << a << " is: " << c << endl ;
   break;
  bool repeat = true;
   }


   {
  case 8:
   cout << " Enter the value that you want the tangent to be taken of"                           <<endl;
  cin >> a ; 
  c=tan(a);
  cout << " The tangent of " << a << " is: " << c << endl ;

  break;
  bool repeat = true;
   } 


   {
   case 0:
   cout << "Ending the program" << endl;
   return 0;}

   break;
   bool repeat = true;
     }
    } while (repeat = true );
     return 0;  
     }
```

Comment: Hmm, just wrote an answer and then noticed that your code already works fine as it is, despite of many problems. Do you have the (correct) feeling that it may just coincidentally do what you want it to do, and you want to know how to do it in a more structured way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is few moments.

Call

```
using namespace std;
```

just believe - is bad idea;

In conditions like if() or while() use operator == instead of =. Because "=" - is assigne operator, and return value depended on success of operation. And "==" is compare operator.

Ow and figure one more missunderstanding. Using bool rezult = true; is wrong. You should use rezult = true; Because every time when you write type specifer you create local variable in context of case, and this don`t affect rezult declared in main

My opinion for your question is little change:
from:

```
do{ 
int x;
...
case 0:
   cout << "Ending the program" << endl;
   return 0;}

   break;
   bool repeat = true;
     }
    } while (repeat = true );
```

to

```
do{ 
 int x;
 ...

 case 0:
  cout << "Ending the program" << endl;
  repeat = false;}
  break;
  }
} while (repeat == true);
```

and if you need a bit more calculations you can wrapped it to new cicle something like:

```
while(new_condtion == true) {
  do {
  ...
  } while(repeat == true);
  //change new_condtion
}
```

Comment: He is using `using namespace std;` within the body of a loop. That's a rare use, but pretty harmless. The guideline is to avoid `using namespace` at global scope in header files.

Answer (score 0):

Don't redefine `repeat` within switch case.   This creates a different variable named `repeat` which, although it has the same name, is not the variable named `repeat` defined before the loop.    This is what you get when you copy a definition of the form `bool repeat = true;` into multiple places.

The continuation condition for the loop  (`repeat = true`) will also loop forever.  Comparison is two `=` signs, not one.